# Get Intraday prices for a few tickers with specific dates

Tags: python-3.x, bloomberg

Using xbbg,I am trying to get intraday prices for some tickers with specific dates. My data set looks like this (please ignore end_date):

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRjfX.png)

I tried the below function ( ticker & start_date are column names mentioned in my dataset). I get the error as :( KeyError 'allday').

`
from xbbg import blp
import datetime
from xbbg import const
import pandas as pd

```
def earlierStartConfig(row):
    tkr = row["ticker"]
    dtSession = row["start_date"]
    minsEarlier = 1

    exch_config = const.exch_info(tkr)
    session = exch_config['allday']
    hours,mins= ( int(s) for s in session[0].split(':') )

#Get the exchange configuration for this ticker

     session[0] = (dtSession + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours,minutes=mins-        minsEarlier)).strftime('%H:%M')
#Bring the session start time forward by one minute

#Genearate a new exchange config with the new start time
 return pd.DataFrame([{'tz':exch_config.tz,'allday':session}],index=[exch_config.name])
```

`

Comment: How is `xbbg` supposed to know what exchange those equities trade on? Your list is SEDOL ids: you need to convert to the Bloomberg ticker, via `bdp()` and the TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE field. eg `0718875 Equity` is equivalent to `RIO LN Equity`. `xbbg` can use the `LN` part via `assets.yaml` to find the `EquityLondon` exchange info.

Comment: yes -- it reads ticker properly, but for futures ticker such as 'ZSIU3 INDEX' it throws me the key error :'allday' -- despite mentioning dt = datetime.datetime(2023,7,5).

Comment: Think about what `xbbg` is doing: it is trying to deduce what exchange a particular asset is trading on. It has a different strategy depending on the "Yellow Key" (Equity, Index, Comdty etc). For indices (yellow key = Index) it tries to find a match in `assets.yml` for either ZSIU3 or just ZSI. This ticker isn't in the as-installed file, so you have to add it yourself, so that it finds the "FuturesEuropeEurex" exchange. Personally I am not a fan of these config files, I would pull the exchange info from Bloomberg and local times from the FUT_TRADING_HRS field.